# Sound volume keys sometimes stop working in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, sound

I have a Ubuntu 13.04 installation (with xubuntu-desktop installed if that matters). My problem is that sometimes the sound hotkeys (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> / <kbd>F11</kbd> /<kbd>F12</kbd>) just stop working (I can still change the sound volume from the sound applet).

I've tried running `xev` - it looks like the system just ignores these hotkeys (nothing is shown in the output).

Not sure if this is a related problem, but when the system boots, the sound level is always set to maximum as soon as, e.g., screen brightness level is remembered and restored correctly.

P.S. My hardware is eeePC 1005HA. The system is not a clean installation, it's being upgraded since 9.10.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like restarting `xfce4-volumed` fixes the problem. I guess I just need to create a respective script that will run on startup.

Comment: Any idea what the equivalent is in vanilla Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Open, **System Setting** and Go **Keyboard**, After Select **Shortcut** Tab and finally select **Sound and Media** and now you can show list and select your hotkeys to up down volume

[image]

Comment: Xubuntu seems to have a different dialog for these settings. Anyway, I believe that shortcuts themselves are set up correctly, because most of the time they work fine. It looks like **sometimes** something fails to launch on system boot, preventing the shortcuts from working. Any ideas where and what should I look for?

Comment: That doesn't recover the functionality for me. They're already mapped that way.